# Capture Handshake with WPS disabled

Tags: authentication, wireless

I just got into exploring network cracking. Honestly, just to learn how the process works.

I am not curious about cracking the handshake as much as capturing it.

It seems when I set up a test router with WPS disabled i cant crack it for the life of me.

I am very new. Should I be running deauth set to infinity and let Airodump-ng listen for a few hours?

Also if someone could be so kind to give me a timeframe as to how long it takes to capture a handshake? My second test router I can capture the handshake in a minute.

thank you all for your help, I did run a search and was unable to locate an answer.

Apologizes if I am offending experts.

Answer (score 1):

WPS - Wifi Protected Setup. Technology used to provide connection by 8-digit PIN code. When you are try to connect with pin code, router will check first 4 digits (10^4). If it is not right, you will receive a disconnect after M4 packet. If it's right - we will know a half of PIN. Last half it 3 digit (3^10) + 1 digit (hash sum). It's fastest way to crack the router but not always. Some routers can block wps if it can see brutforce. And signal must be strong.

WPA - you need a handshake to crack a router. But you need to use password list for brutforce.

WEP - I don't remember, it seems, that it very easy to crack and you dont need a password list for that.

For your question - to crack wpa you need:
 1. Enable monitor mode with airmon-ng
 2. Start airodump-ng
 3. Start aireplay-ng in another terminal, read help and send deauth packects to router
 4. After that you will see "Handshake found!!" in airodump terminal.
 5. Save them to file
 6. Start Aircrack-ng with password list and hope, that needed password will be in your password list.